# Oracle PL SQL: Comparing ref cursor results returned by two stored procs

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I was given a stored proc which generates an open cursor which is passed as output to a reporting tool. I re-wrote this stored proc to improve performance. What I'd like to do is to show that the two result sets are the same for a given set of input parameters.

Something that is the equivalent of:

```
select * from CURSOR_NEW
minus
select * from CURSOR_OLD
     union all
select * from CURSOR_OLD
minus
select * from CURSOR_NEW
```

Each cursor returns several dozen columns from a large subset of tables. Each row has an id value, and a long list of other column values for that id. I would want to check:

1. Both cursors are returning the same set of ids (I already checked this)
2. Both cursors have the same list of values for each id they have in common

If it was just one or two columns, I could concatenate them and find a hash and then sum it up over the cursor.  Or another way might be to create a parent program that inserted the cursor results into a global temp table and compared the results. But since it's several dozen columns I'm trying to find a less brute force approach to doing the comparison.

Also it would be nice if the solution was scalable for other situations that involved different cursors, so it wouldn't have to be manually re-written each time, since this is a situation I'm running into more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this. It was a lot more complicated than I expected. I ended up using some DBMS_SQL procedures that allow converting REFCURSORs to defined cursors. Oracle has documentation on it here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS00001

After that I concatenated the row values into a string and printed the hash. For bigger cursors, I will change concat_col_vals to use a CLOB to prevent it from overflowing.

p_testCursors returns a simple refcursor for example purposes.

```
declare
  cx_1              sys_refcursor;
  c                 NUMBER;
  desctab           DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  colcnt            NUMBER;
  stringvar         VARCHAR2(4000);
  numvar            NUMBER;
  datevar           DATE;
  concat_col_vals   varchar2(4000);
  col_hash          number;
  h                 raw(32767);
  n                 number;

BEGIN
  p_testCursors(cx_1);

  c := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(cx_1);
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, colcnt, desctab);

  -- Define columns:
  FOR i IN 1 .. colcnt LOOP
    IF desctab(i).col_type = 2 THEN
      DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c, i, numvar);
    ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = 12 THEN
      DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c, i, datevar);
      -- statements
    ELSE
      DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c, i, stringvar, 4000);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  -- Fetch rows with DBMS_SQL package:
  WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(c) > 0 LOOP
  concat_col_vals := '~';
    FOR i IN 1 .. colcnt LOOP
      IF (desctab(i).col_type = 1) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c, i, stringvar);
        --Dbms_Output.Put_Line(stringvar);
        concat_col_vals := concat_col_vals || '~' || stringvar;
      ELSIF (desctab(i).col_type = 2) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c, i, numvar);
        --Dbms_Output.Put_Line(numvar);
        concat_col_vals := concat_col_vals || '~' || to_char(numvar);
      ELSIF (desctab(i).col_type = 12) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c, i, datevar);
        --Dbms_Output.Put_Line(datevar);
        concat_col_vals := concat_col_vals || '~' || to_char(datevar);
        -- statements
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(concat_col_vals);
    col_hash :=  DBMS_UTILITY.GET_SQL_HASH(concat_col_vals, h, n);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Return Value: ' || TO_CHAR(col_hash));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hash: ' || h);
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy task for Oracle.

**Very good article** you can find on dba-oracle web:
[Sql patterns symmetric diff](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_patterns_symmetric_diff.htm)
and [Convert set to join sql parameter](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_set_to_join_sql_parameter.htm)

If you need it often, you can:

- add "hash column" and fill it always with insert using trigger, or
- for each table in cursor output get unique value (create unique index) and compare only this column wiht anijoin

and you can find other possibilities in article.